# PendingIntent getBroadcast and getActivity at same Time

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to implement pendingIntent.getbroadcast and pendingIntent.getactivity at same time.
Actually my application is sending the notification When user Click on my notification my Application will start(by using getActivity) and It also broadcast to my broadcast receiver to perform some activity by my broad cast receiver.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Functionality that I want to achieve is when I click on notificaion it will open my activity and broadcast a message as well
Thanks in Advance